# how to leave out blank rows using fgetcsv

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have been working on importing a csv file into a mysql database. Problem is my client gets the files already with some bad formatting. the rows end at 43 but the file goes down to 65078!!

When importing, the script takes forever. What can I do to make sure just the rows from 0 to 44 get imported? Here's the code i'm using.

```
  <table>
<?php
//fgetcsv($handle, 1024, delimiter)
$file = fopen("prices.csv", "r");
$row = 0;

    while($csv_line = fgetcsv($file,1024)) {

      if($row ==    4){
        echo "How many headers do we have: ".count($csv_line)."<tr>";

         foreach($csv_line as $header){

           if($header !== NULL){
            print "<td>$header</td>";
           }
         }
         echo "</tr>";
      } 

      if($row > 6) {

        echo '<tr>';

        for ($i = 0, $j = count($csv_line); $i < $j; $i++) {

          echo '<td>'.$csv_line[$i].'</td>';

        }

        echo "</tr>\n";

      } else {

        $row++;

      }

    } 
?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number of filled rows isn't fixed, you can use similar approach with:

```
if (empty($line)) { break; }
```

Your comment give me an idea for a better solution:

Here http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php appears this "A blank line in a CSV file will be returned as an array comprising a single null field" so maybe this helps:

`while(($csv_line = fgetcsv($file,1024)) && $csv_line[0]) {`

Will read only until finds an empty row.

Comment: I think I could do that but won't the file still get parsed and that would still consume too much time? because for php to know that the row is empty, it still would have gone till the end of the file...

Comment: Your comment give me an idea for a better solution:

Here [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) appears this "A blank line in a CSV file will be returned as an array comprising a single null field" so maybe this helps: 

`while(($csv_line = fgetcsv($file,1024)) && $csv_line[0]) {`

Will read only until finds an empty row (I will update the reply)

Comment: @ leticia I have a similiar question: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703373/csv-file-generated-table-with-php-omit-variables-for-start-and-end-creating-ta)

Comment: is your second one correct? what if the first element is null of the row, but there are others not null?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `if ($row >= 44) { break; }` at the bottom of the loop so it'll exit once you reach row 44.

Comment: thanks for the help. I changed it as such but it just won't stop executing! The script is returning a page filled with a lot of whitespace at the bottom...

Comment: Don't put your `$row++` inside one of the if() clauses. it'd only increment if that particular clause matches. it should be at the top level of the loop, so it increments regardless of what happens inside theloop.